# Which would you rather use in JavaScript: init() or main()?

Tags: javascript, preferences, program-entry-point, init

I know init() and main() aren't special in JavaScript, but I've seen them used by countless programmers on the web.  Seeing this I thought I'd add a function to my JavaScript library that checks for the init() or main() functions and then executes them once the body loads.  My question is would you rather type init or main.  I think this might be a dumb question seeing I could most likely just run it to check for both but it would be nice to have a standard (If you know what I mean...).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most common standard I see is `$(function() { ... });` ;)

Comment: It is a personal opinion. Some people name variables X way and others Y. Pick what you think works best or follow the pattern of the libraries you are working with.

Comment: @Plynx that is calling a function on document ready, not what the OP is asking. And ready is also over used.

Comment: What I wanted to know is out of init() and main() which do you think is nicer/common/easier-to-type?

Comment: @epascarello I should know better than to make jokes in this crowd. I even thought to add a winky face!

Comment: @Harvest I actually use a singleton object named for my app (capitalized) with a `run()` function, along with other configuration properties.

Comment: @Plynx, My funny bone is not working today. I missed the wink with all of that bracket nonsense before it. 11:30 and I need more coffee.

Comment: @Plynx Yeh I caught on to that. *ha* well thanks for everyone's input i think i'm going to use main() since it's used in other languages and just simply looks sexier than init()..